# MySQL str_to_date problem

Tags: mysql, sql

What's wrong with this? `str_to_date('26/04/2011 00:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y')`
It gives `Error Code: 1292 Truncated incorrect date value: '26/04/2011 00:00:00'`

**Update**: The problem is the `00:00:00`, if I remove it it works. How can edit the `'%d/%m/%Y'` to accept the time? `'%d/%m/%Y %h:%m:%s'` doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the  00:00:00 in your pattern?

Comment: @Pekka sorry I added the update just after your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've specified the time in the value parameter, you should also specify the time components in the date format parameter.

```
str_to_date('26/04/2011 00:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s')
```

either that, or drop the time component from your date value:

```
str_to_date('26/04/2011', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

either should work, but you need to be consistent between the two parameters.

Alternatively, you could specify the format so that it has fixed values in the time component:

```
str_to_date('26/04/2011 00:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y 00:00:00')
```

this will work, but only if the time component is always `00:00:00`.

Comment: str_to_date('26/04/2011', '%d/%m/%Y') works but I can't remove the 0s from my data. With '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s' I still get the same error

Comment: @Michael - see my edited answer for a third alternative which might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
str_to_date('26/04/2011 00:00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Note the capital `%H` for hour (00-24) instead of `%h` (01-12).