# MySql - STR_TO_DATE and filter, original format 1/8/2015 12:00:00 AM

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm learning basic MySQl on my own, and I can't figure this out. I need to return entries which have a print_date 2 weeks or more before than today's date. I cannot change the date format in my data source, which is like so: 1/8/2015 12:00:00 AM

So, I believe I need to first convert this to datetime, and then filter.  Both the below return Null for my date field though:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1/8/2015 12:00:00 AM','%Y/%m/%d 12:00:00 %M') print_date
FROM store_data
...

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(print_date,'%Y/%m/%d 12:00:00 %M')
FROM store_data
...
```

After that I need to add the filter for earlier than 2 weeks from today's date, which I have some work on but can't get past the str_to_date. Thanks!

Comment: In the string '1/8/2015', you appear to be under the impression that '1' is the year and '2015 is the day. I find this unlikely. Further, I suspect that '12:00:00' is a reference to hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this myself, but looking at this tutorial (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/) and at your code it seems like you don't want the time? So it should probably just be `%m/%d/%Y` while ignoring the rest of the characters?

Comment: Here is a link to a question where the poster is trying to do a similar thing to yourself, hope it helps :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952712/mysql-str-to-date-problem (See the first answer)

Comment: combining comment 1 & 2 accomplished my first task, thank you! I thought i was supposed to put the DESIRED date format after the commma, not the current, and correct, I don't need the time. so, STR_TO_DATE(print_date,'%m/%d/%Y') worked. Now on to the filtering..